# Regex match for alphanumeric chars and one * which should be a total length of 3

Tags: java, javascript, regex

How can I write a regex for alphanumeric chars allowing one or two stars and restricting the total string length to 3.

Ex : the below strings length is 3

```
*12  or *2* 0r *a* or *B* or **2
```

So, the `*` symbol can occur at last or middle or at the first of `*12`.  Similarly, if you take the last example `**2`  you see more than one `*` symbol and that can occur in any order of that string.

Comment: Your example has a total string length of more than 3

Comment: I mean *12 should be length of 3

Comment: So in your example string you would expect three matches?

Comment: @aditya86c - you should remove mention of commas and spaces from your question now that you've removed them from your example strings. Also, all of your examples have a * as the first character, so does that mean `A**` and `AB*` are _not_ permitted? (In my answer I assumed they are not permitted.)

Comment: Fantastic question.  I learned a lot!  See answer below.  Hope it works for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could always use a lookahead assertion in javascript. Its a little tricky but it's better suited to fine-tune any specific permutations.

`/^(?=(?:[^*]*\*){1,2}[^*]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9*]{3}$/`

Expanded:

```
^                        # beginning of line
  (?=                         # start lookahead
      (?:                       # non-capture group
          [^*]*                    # optional not '*' characters
          \*                       # '*' character
      ){1,2}                    # end group, do 1 or 2 times
      [^*]*                     # optional not '*' characters
      $                         # end of line
  )                          # end lookahead
  [a-zA-Z0-9*]{3}            # back at begining of line. at this point there will
                             # be only 1 or 2 '*' characters in the line.
                             # match exactly 3 of alphanumeric characters or '*'
$                        # end of line
```

Substitute any requirements you need.
Below is a perl test case, javascript is not my strong point.

```
@samps = qw(
 *12  1*2  12*  **1  *1*  1**  ***
 a*12 a1*2 a12* **a1 *a1* a1** ****
 *2   *2   2*   *1   1*   **   
);

for $teststr (@samps) {
   if ($teststr =~ /^(?=(?:[^*]*\*){1,2}[^*]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9*]{3}$/) {
      print "$teststr passed\n";
   }
   else {
      print "$teststr failed\n";
   }
}
```

Output:

```
*12 passed
1*2 passed
12* passed
**1 passed
*1* passed
1** passed
*** failed
a*12 failed
a1*2 failed
a12* failed
**a1 failed
*a1* failed
a1** failed
**** failed
*2 failed
*2 failed
2* failed
*1 failed
1* failed
** failed
```

**Edit** For @bozdoz

I didn't realize a string might be scraped for multiple instances of this. If so, the regex can be generalized to be used with/without delimeters.
The important thing is that this scales up very well if the requirements change to, for example 8 total characters and only 2-4 asterisks.

Examples:

*no delimeters* other than begin/end of string:

```
  /
    ^
     (?= [a-z0-9*]{3} $ )
     (?:[a-z0-9]*\*){1,2} [a-z0-9]*
    $
  /xi
```

delimeter is *\s*, the context is single-line and global. Data is captured in group 1

```
 /
   (?:^|\s)
    (?= [a-z0-9*]{3} (?:$|\s) )
    ( (?:[a-z0-9]*\*){1,2} [a-z0-9]* )
   (?=$|\s)
 /xig
```

delimeter is *[^a-z0-9*]*, the context is single-line and global. Data is captured in group 1

```
 /
   (?:^|[^a-z0-9*])
    (?= [a-z0-9*]{3} (?:$|[^a-z0-9*]) )
    ( (?:[a-z0-9]*\*){1,2} [a-z0-9]* )
   (?=$|[^a-z0-9*])
 /xig
```

Comment: It didn't work for me on PHP or javascript.  However, I trust your test, and I am glad you actually tested for between 1 and 2 word characters and 1 and 2 * characters in 3 character words.  The "approved" answer didn't even do that.  +1  :)

Comment: @bozdoz - Thanks! Added 3 regex's to parse single/multiple occurances per string. This scales much better than trying to handle all permutations.

Answer (score 1):

This regex works with a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind).  I have tested it with PHP in codepad [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ybbFgv).

```
(?<![\w*])(\w(?!\w\w)|\*(?!\*\*)){3}(?![\w*])
```

It basically looks for a three character word that doesn't have three word characters or three star characters.  `(?<![\w*])` removes words that follow a word character or a * and `(?![\w*])` removes words that precede them (therefore returning ONLY three character word-segments).

Javascript doesn't exactly have lookbehinds, so I tried to adapt on a technique used [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript).  I then came up with the following regex, tested in jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/GreHu/).

```
/(?![\w*])(.?)(\w(?!\w\w)|\*(?!\*\*)){3}(?![\w*])/g
```

**Hope this helps!!!!!!!!** <- regex's drive me a little crazy

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9*]{2}[^*]|[a-zA-Z0-9*][^*][a-zA-Z0-9*]|[^*][a-zA-Z0-9*]{2}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work.So far, I came up with this [a-zA-Z0-9*]+ but this matches *12ThisKeepsGrowing

Comment: Thanks simon.But, this regex matches for any string length. I am testing it in rubular.com

Comment: I interpreted _restricting the total string length to 3_ as _maximum 3_ characters. I fixed it again.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: for your updated question without the commas and optional spaces:

```
/^(\*[A-Z0-9]{2}|\*[A-Z0-9]\*|\*\*[A-Z0-9])$/i
```

Your examples don't include the alphanumeric character first, e.g., `A**`, but if you want that I'm sure you can figure it out from what I've already given you.

(see below for comment on mixed case)

My original answer:

```
/^(\*[A-Z0-9]{2}|\*[A-Z0-9]\*|\*\*[A-Z0-9])(, *(\*[A-Z0-9]{2}|\*[A-Z0-9]\*|\*\*[A-Z0-9]))*$/i
```

That is the JavaScript syntax with the "i" option to make it case-insensitive. I can't be bothered looking up the Java equivalent for case-insensitive matching, but if necessary you could always change each `[A-Z0-9]` part to `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

Also you can use `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9]` if you extend your definition of "alphanumeric" to include underscores.

Answer (score 0):

There are three cases:

```
\w[*\w]{2}  # case 1, string begins with word character, last 2 can be stars
\*\w[*\w]   # case 2, string begins with 1 star, last can be a star
\*{2}\w     # case 3, string begins with 2 stars, last cannot be a star
```

Taken together, and adding the necessary start and end of string assertions, we get:

```
^(\w[*\w]{2}|\*\w[*\w]|\*{2}\w)$
```

But this solution is not quite correct because the `\w` character class allows not only alphanumerics but also the `_` character. Therefore, we substitute a bracketed character class `[a-zA-Z0-9]` for `\w` and get:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9][*a-zA-Z0-9]{2}|\*[a-zA-Z0-9][*a-zA-Z0-9]|\*{2}[a-zA-Z0-9])$
```